# Trying to reverse my for-loops (creating a hourglass)

Tags: c, for-loop, hourglass

I'm trying to create an hourglass, It seems as if my spacing for the reverse for-loop is messing up, and I don't know how I would remove the extra 5 without messing up the for-loop.

My code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

long long number;

printf("Enter a long number\n");
printf("Enter your number = ");
scanf("%lld", &number);


for(int j=1; j<= (log10(number)+1); j++){

    for(int i=1; i<= (log10(number)+1) - (j-1); i++){
       printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));
    
   }

printf("\n");
printf("%*s", 2*j-1, "  ");

}

for(int j=(log10(number)+1); j>=1; j--){
    
    for(int i=(log10(number)+1)-(j-1); i>=1 ; i--){
        printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));
    
   }
   
printf("\n");
printf("%*s", 2*j-1, "  ");

}



   return 0;
}
```

---

My output:

```
Enter a long number                                                                                                                             
Enter your number = 12345                                                                                                                       
5   4   3   2   1                                                                                                                               
  5   4   3   2                                                                                                                                 
   5   4   3                                                                                                                                    
     5   4                                                                                                                                      
       5                                                                                                                                        
         5                                                                                                                                      
         4   5                                                                                                                                  
       3   4   5                                                                                                                                
     2   3   4   5                                                                                                                              
   1   2   3   4   5
```

What would be the best way for removing the extra 5 on top, and what did I do wrong with the spacing?

---

What I'm trying to output:

```
Enter a long number
Enter your number = 12345
5   4   3   2   1
  5   4   3   2
    5   4   3
      5   4
        5   
      4   5
    3   4   5
  2   3   4   5
1   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: The problem with your code is that it conflates the numbers with their spacing.  This is OK for the first loop, but it causes problems in the second loop because the orientation of the numbers is reversed.  I suggest you maintain a separate counter for the second loop to handle the spacing.

Comment: like the separate counter being a new variable??

Comment: Yes, a new variable.

Comment: The extra `5` can be removed from the first loop by changing it to `for(int j=1; j<= (log10(number)); j++)` (removing the `+ 1` from the condition).

Comment: Should the new variable be an int or long? I'm having trouble picturing it.

Comment: It's just an ordinary `int` counter.  You're already using one in `printf("%*s", 2*j-1, "  ");` you just need to make it independent of your other numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indent your rows before writing the numbers. For the second loop, skip the first row.

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    long long number;
    
    printf("Enter a long number\n");
    printf("Enter your number = ");
    scanf("%lld", &number);

    for(int j=1; j<= (log10(number)+1); j++){
    
        printf("%*s", 2*(j-1), "");  // indent row
        for(int i=1; i<= (log10(number)+1) - (j-1); i++){
           printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));
        
        }
    
       printf("\n");
    }


    for(int j=(log10(number)+1)-1; j>=1; j--){
        
        printf("%*s", 2*(j-1), "");  // indent row
        for(int i=(log10(number)+1)-(j-1); i>=1 ; i--){
            printf("%d   ", (number%((int)pow(10, i)))/(int)pow(10, i-1));
        }
       
       printf("\n");
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Enter a long number
Enter your number = 12345
5   4   3   2   1   
  5   4   3   2   
    5   4   3   
      5   4   
        5   
      4   5   
    3   4   5   
  2   3   4   5   
1   2   3   4   5
```